# How to read out an USB Rfid Reader imitating an HID keyboard using Linux and Python3

Tags: keyboard, python-3.x, debian, hid, rfid

I'm using an Rfid Reader (a small usb stick) which imitates an HID keyboard on Debian Linux (Squeeze).

less -f /dev/input/event2 gives me a bunch of gibberish on the screen the moment an rfid tag is scanned. By using an evdev Python library ( http://bit.ly/kZkO2b ) I could actually decode the string correctly.

But I think I'm barking up the wrong tree. This seems much too complicated. If the rfid reader works like an HID keyboard I should be able to access it by using basic functions like sys.stdin, right? So how is this done properly?

Comment: If it behaved exactly like a standard keyboard, it would spew that giberrish over your word processor, so stdin doesn't make sense. And the event device probably needs evdev. But maybe the RFID reader creates another device too, that can be read like a file?

Comment: I missed the forest through the trees. I was logged in via ssh (it's and embedded device) and the only thing I had to do was to read /dev/tty0 using io.open * facepalm *

Comment: Don't forget to post the solution as an answer and accept it, so that it might help others in the future. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the user hasn't replied here since May 2011, but *did* find a solution to his problem as stated in his comment, I am hereby taking the liberty of posting said solution and getting this question out of the "Unanswered" queue.

---

The problem was solved after the user realized he was logged into the embedded device through [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). He proceeded by simply reading [`/dev/tty0`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.5) using [`io.open`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/io.html) from the [Python 3 standard library](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/index.html).